# How to achieve recursive hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to a query which can convert below **data available** into the **expected data** (Refer below example)

**Data Available**

```
Prnt Child
-----------------
BU1 BU2
BU1 BU3
BU1 BU4
BU3 BU8
BU3 BU9
BU4 BU5
BU4 BU6
BU4 BU7
BU6 BU10
BU6 BU11
BU7 BU12
```

Expected Output

```
Prnt Child
-----------------------
BU1 BU2
BU1 BU3
BU1 BU4
BU1 BU8
BU1 BU9
BU1 BU5
BU1 BU6
BU1 BU7
BU1 BU10
BU1 BU11
BU1 BU12
BU2 BU2
BU3 BU8
BU3 BU9
BU4 BU6
BU4 BU7
BU4 BU5
BU4 BU10
BU4 BU11
BU4 BU12

and so on....
```

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Welcome to S.O.! I'm not part of the downvoters, but i'm guessing a similar question already exists. And people here don't like "I need a script that does X" type questions. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hard to tell from expected output what the pattern is... but then I never did well on those type of questions in school.

Comment: There is no obvious relation to the input and the output. Please edit your question to describe what you are trying to do in plain language.

Comment: New to SO, looked up already to find something similar but was not able to achieve what I needed. So posted here to see if I can get some help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` in a hierarchical query:

```
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( prnt ) AS prnt,
       chld
FROM   your_table
CONNECT BY PRIOR chld = prnt
UNION ALL
SELECT chld, chld
FROM   your_table
ORDER BY prnt, chld;
```

Comment: UNION ALL gives duplicate records bu Union works fine